# TikZ picture: two arrow; one over the other

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
  \[
        \begin{tikzpicture}
         \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=1em,minimum width=2em]{
              A &   & G \\
                & S &   \\
         };
         \path[-stealth]
            (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$f$} (m-1-3)
            (m-1-1)  edge [bend right] node [left] {$p\;$} (m-2-2)
            (m-1-3) edge node [right] {$\;q$} (m-2-2)
            (m-2-2) edge node [right] {$\epsilon$} (m-1-1);
         \path[-stealth]
            ([yshift=5pt]m-1-1) edge node [right] {$g$} ([yshift=5pt]m-1-3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

I dare you to compile it. Then you will get a disgusting output. What I want is to get the two arrow on top one over the other (just like corolary 1.3.1.5, page 70, in the notes on http://math.umn.edu/~kwlan/articles/cpt-PEL-type-thesis-revision.pdf).

Can anyone help? I would love if the solution didn't modify too much the way I coded the diagram since it is the way I always do it (with the matrix) but beggers can't be choosers, so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an attempt to fix it by using the `.east` and `.west` anchors:

[image]

### Notes:

- Not sure why you were using math mode -- I have removed that in the below MWE.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
         \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=1em,minimum width=2em]{
              A &   & G \\
                & S &   \\
         };
         \path[-stealth]
            (m-1-1.east) edge node [above,yshift=1.0ex] {$f$} (m-1-3.west)
            (m-1-1) edge [bend right] node [left] {$p\;$} (m-2-2)
            (m-1-3) edge node [right] {$\;q$} (m-2-2)
            (m-2-2) edge node [right] {$\epsilon$} (m-1-1);
         \path[-stealth]
            ([yshift=5pt]m-1-1.east) edge node [below,,yshift=-1.0ex] {$g$} ([yshift=5pt]m-1-3.west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's quite easy with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em]
A \arrow[yshift=.85ex]{rr}{f}
  \arrow[yshift=-.45ex,swap]{rr}{g}
  \arrow[yshift=-.4ex,bend right,swap]{dr}{p}
&&
G \arrow{dl}{q} \\
&
S \arrow[swap]{ul}{\epsilon}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here a variant of Peter's code but without matrix and some adjustment with the position of some arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path          node (A) {$A$}
    (0:4cm)    node (G) {$G$}
    (-60:4cm)  node (S) {$S$};
 \path[-stealth]
   (A) edge [bend right] node [left]  {$p\;$}      (S)
   (G) edge              node [right] {$\;q$}      (S)
   (S) edge              node [right] {$\epsilon$} (A)
   ([yshift=-2.5pt]A.east) edge node [above,yshift= 1.0ex]  {$f$} ([yshift=-2.5pt]G.west)        
   ([yshift= 2.5pt]G.west) edge node [below,yshift=-1.0ex]  {$g$} ([yshift= 2.5pt]A.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]